# Calaculate top margin using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I need to calculate value for top margin dynamically from a div of fixed sized containing image. The image's height is variable.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
 <img src="path for image" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {width:300px; height:300px;}
img {margin-top: ??????}
```

`margin-top` should be calculated by deducting the image's height from div's height..

Is it possible by using SASS?

Comment: You can use **CSS** [calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) - `margin-top: calc(100% - 300px)`

Comment: I don't think you can do it with SASS, here is a mini working code of a possible solution using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/GZyZk/

Comment: Are you sure that you need to calculate the margin-top or are you only trying to position the image on the bottom of the div?

Comment: actually i am trying to position the image to the center of the div..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to position the image to the center of the div, **you don't need *margin-top***: vertical-align it's your solution!

I made an example for you:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="battleground">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1hQn32D.jpg" alt="Titanfall Image" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.battleground {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.battleground img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And if you wish, [you can play here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRUh9/).